# how to read #document in Beautiful Soup python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Hi I am learning python so tried to make a simple web scraping script with beautiful soup & request.
I am trying to capture one html page's content. html is like this -

```
<frame name="name", src="..">
    #document
        <html>
            <head>
               <script language="JavaScript" src="nav.js"></script>
            <frameset>
                <table>
........
```

I have tried like this:

```
with urllib.request.urlopen(url+page['src']) as frameurl:
    response = frameurl.read()
   # print('response',response)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response,'html.parser')
    table =soup.find_all('#document') #want to read the data under this
    frames=getAllFrames(soup)
    for frame in frames:
        if(frame['name'] == 'leftnav'):
            print('navbar:',frame)
            #print('test',frame.getHtml())
            #frames =soup.find_all("frame")
            print('html',frame.find('html')) #gives None
            for child in frame.children:  #nothing 
                print('child',child)
```

how can I read the data/tables inside #document, particularly the tag frameset. 
the frameset also has a .html which is blank page.(I have very basic knowledge of html also)

Comment: Have you read through the [Beautiful Soup documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)? It is pretty good.

Comment: What is `getAllFrames`?

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: ^^^ yup... seeing url if possible would help

Comment: the url will not be accessible , its a private site.